# JSF ui:repeat with pagination

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to know how to do a ui:repeat with multiple pages, i click the previous/next button to view the next set of data.

currently i have a ui:repeat

```
<ui:repeat id="repeat5" value="#{getData.data}" var="lst2" varStatus="loop">
```

I can view the content (basically images) in a rows/columns but all the data is displayed in the same screen but i would like to show only 5 rows and 4columns and then use the previous/next button to view the remaining images in the 5 rows/ 4 columns layout.

Currently i can specify only column configuration like below, how do i get the specified rows.

```
<h:panelGrid  id="panelGrid3" columns="4" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
```

**UPDATE 1 (Code for Rasmus Franke)**

Pls find the code as requested by you.

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
<p:tabView id="tabView" >
    <p:tab title="Image Viewer" id="Viewer" titleStyle="height:30px">
        <p:layout>
        <p:layoutUnit id="layoutEast" position="east" size="350" style="height:200px">
                        <p:commandButton type="button" onclick=""  
                                         icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-w"/>  
                        <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="switchPage(1,29);"  
                                         icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-e"/>
                        <h:panelGrid  id="panelGrid3" columns="5" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                            <ui:repeat id="repeat5" value="#{getData.data}" var="imagesLst2" varStatus="loop">
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <p:commandLink id="cl3" action="#{getData.imageID(imagesLst2.imageID)}" update=":mainForm:tabView:example">
                                            <p:graphicImage id="gi3" value="#{imagesStreamer.image}" styleClass="bord" 
                                                            onmousedown="mouseDown(this)" alt="image not available3"  width="60" height="60"
                                                            style="#{loop.index > 29 ? 'visibility: hidden;' : ''}">
                                                <f:param name="id5" value="#{imagesLst2.imageID}" />
                                            </p:graphicImage>
                                        </p:commandLink>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: Is your command link inside ui repeat working ok? I'm facing problems on this, I don't know if is a jsf limitation.

Comment: Is it request scope? You load your list on each time managedBean are created? Thanks

Comment: Oh, my problem was related to requestScoped and I need to bring again the data from the DB. With sessionScoped it worked as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the pagination to work server side or client side?

If server side: you need to make a property in your managed bean, and set it to your pagination values: for example and int that gets a value 5, for page 5. Use this data to modify getData.data so that it contains only the data for that page. This way you will only have to fetch relevant data that is displayed for each page, but you will have to make a http request for each pagination click, either via a normal post or via ajax.

If client side: All data for all pages should be included in the ui:repeat to make it available for javascript modification on the client side. In other words, as it is now. Add "visibility: hidden;" to all rows except the first page server side with `style="#{loop.index > x ? 'visibility: hidden;' : ''}"` where x is the number of rows shown. Then make a javascript function that is called when the page is changed, with parameters for page number and number of elements per page.

```
function switchPage(page, numPerPage){
    var first = (page-1) * numPerPage;
    var last = (page) * numPerPage;
    $('#panelGrid3 tr').show();
    $('#panelGrid3 tr').each(function(i, e){
        if(i >= first || i <= last){
           $(e).show();
        }else{
           $(e).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried the above option (client side) the style part works fine, but i am not able to get the script working please check the below code for the button  <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="switchPage(1,29);" />, how will the $('#panelGrid3 tr').show(); and .each(function(i,e) works.

Comment: $('#panelGrid3 tr') selects all rows (tr elements) inside of the container with id panelGrid3. show() removes "visibility: hidden;" from them (with the purpose of resetting the table). The function passed to each() loops over all rows. i is the index of the loop and e is the element (tr). One possible place of error is the selector #panelGrid3, if that element is inside of a JSF container, JSF adds to its ID. Please post more of your HTML code, and the JS error if you want further help!

Comment: Rasmus Franke, please find the code updated in the question part

Comment: Your panelGrid is inside several containers which will add to your id (to make it unique even when repeating stuff), so your clientId will be something like mainForm:tabView:possibleLayoutId:panelGrid3. The colons need to be escaped for jQuery so this is not very nice. I recommend making a DIV surrounding panelGrid3 and giving it and ID which you can then use in jquery for selecting all table rows. Non-JSF elements such as DIV does not get prepended by container Ids.

Comment: I also recommend using the html inspector/javascript debugger of your browser of choice!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the ui:repeat has offset and size which helps in doing pagination we need to implement the logic in the managed bean (simply keep track of the num of images, displayed images and keep increasing/decreasing the numbers on previous and next button [which will control the pagination]).